# PostgreSQL returning NULL as a row in case query returns empty

Tags: sql, postgresql, rust

I have a generic code which is trying to access field values after query returns.

```
SELECT 
    ROUND(AVG(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (time::timestamp)))) as extended_time
FROM log_info 
WHERE 
    id = 1 AND 
    code = 200;
```

However, this is returning NULL value as single row which is causing my application to crash.

```
for row in &con.query(query, args.as_slice()).unwrap() {
    let extended_time: i32 = row.get("extended_time");
    ...
}
```

crashes with following error :-

```
error retrieving column "extended_time": Conversion(WasNull)
```

Running manually returns

```
 extended_time
-------------

(1 row)
```

Without `AVG` query returns expected result

```
SELECT 
    EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (time::timestamp)) as extended_time
FROM log_info 
WHERE 
    id = 1 AND 
    code = 200;

 extended_time
-------------
(0 rows)
```

Comment: How many rows does the query return if you run it manually?

Comment: @melpomene I should've updated in question earlier :)

Comment: You're selecting a single row (`... where id = 1`). Why use `AVG` at all? Or is `id` not a primary key?

Comment: @melpomene I have edited the query for obvious reasons. Please ignore this

Comment: What do you want the average of 0 rows to be?

Answer (score 1):

An `i32` can't be empty. You should use an [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/index.html) as your query can return `NULL`:

```
let extended_time: Option<i32> = row.get("extended_time");
```